# Can you split up a connection string in app.config?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, app-config

I am very new to app.config files:

In an app.config file which look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
 <connectionStrings>
   <add name="connectionstring" connectionString="Server=server;User ID=bar;Password=foobar" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings> 
</configuration>
```

I want to split up the connection string into various sections like `Server`, `UserId`, etc in a **different** file and then concat it together in my app.config:

Pseucode

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
 <connectionStrings>
   <add name="connectionstring" connectionString=Server+UserId+Password providerName="System.Data.SqlClient />
 </connectionStrings> 
</configuration>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You can export entire connectionstrings section to a different file and use `configSource` to use the load the configuratios from it at runtime.

Comment: Can I store the Server, UserId, and Password as different key-value pairs which I can then concat together?

Comment: You can not inject the values in connection string in configuration file. Can you explain bit more about issue you are trying to solve? Why you need to have username/server/password etc in different file?

Comment: I think the config files are to save your data that is not dynamic. Yet, you can have an `<appSettings>` segment where you can save all these things one by one and then retrieve and concatenate later.